# Why can I pass a reference to a non-static local variable to a function which has a 'static bound?

Tags: lambda, static, rust, lifetime, hyper

I have problems understanding why it is possible to write code like

```
extern crate futures;
extern crate hyper;

use hyper::server::{Http, Request, Response, Service};

struct Environment {}

struct HttpService<'a> {
    pub env: &'a Environment,
}

impl<'a> Service for HttpService<'a> {
    type Request = Request;
    type Response = Response;
    type Future = futures::future::FutureResult<Self::Response, Self::Error>;
    type Error = hyper::Error;

    fn call(&self, _req: Request) -> Self::Future {
        futures::future::ok(Response::new())
    }
}

fn foo() {
    let addr = "127.0.0.1:3000".parse().unwrap();
    let env = Environment {};

    // <<<<< why is the non-static &env accepted here?
    let server = Http::new().bind(&addr, move || Ok(HttpService { env: &env }));

    server.unwrap().run().unwrap();
}
```

The `bind()` method is [defined](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.11.15/hyper/server/struct.Http.html#method.bind) as

```
fn bind<S, Bd>(&self, addr: &SocketAddr, new_service: S) -> Result<Server<S, Bd>>
where
    S: NewService<Request = Request, Response = Response<Bd>, Error = Error> + 'static,
    Bd: Stream<Item = B, Error = Error>,
```

This means that the closure must have a `'static` lifetime which is violated by passing `&env`.

Why does it work in the code above, but not in

```
fn bar() {
    use tokio_core::net::TcpListener;

    let addr = "127.0.0.1:3000".parse().unwrap();
    let env = Environment {};

    let mut core = tokio_core::reactor::Core::new().unwrap();
    let handle = core.handle();

    use futures::Stream;
    use futures::Future;

    let listener = TcpListener::bind(&addr, &handle)
        .unwrap()
        .incoming()
        .for_each(move |(socket, addr)| {
            let svc = HttpService { env: &env };
            let fut = Http::<hyper::Chunk>::new()
                .serve_connection(socket, svc)
                .map(|_| ())
                .map_err(|_| panic!("err"));
            handle.spawn(fut);
            Ok(())
        });
}
```

which fails with the expected lifetime related errors:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for borrow expression due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:50:42
   |
50 |             let svc = HttpService { env: &env };
   |                                          ^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime  as defined on the body at 49:19...
  --> src/main.rs:49:19
   |
49 |           .for_each(move |(socket, addr)| {
   |  ___________________^
50 | |             let svc = HttpService { env: &env };
51 | |             let fut = Http::<hyper::Chunk>::new()
52 | |                 .serve_connection(socket, svc)
...  |
56 | |             Ok(())
57 | |         });
   | |_________^
note: ...so that closure can access `env`
  --> src/main.rs:50:42
   |
50 |             let svc = HttpService { env: &env };
   |                                          ^^^^
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that the type `HttpService<'_>` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  --> src/main.rs:53:18
   |
53 |                 .map(|_| ())
   |                  ^^^
```

Even better, how can I write the latter part using the more powerful `Http::serve_*()` functions?

I am using

- Rust 1.22.1
- Hyper 0.11.15
- Tokio-core 0.1.12

Answer (score 3):

By using the `move` keyword, you've transferred ownership of the `Environment` variable to the closure. This means that the closure itself *has no references*, thus there are no lifetimes involved. The *return* value of the closure has a lifetime tied to the closure itself, but that's allowed.

Note that this case uses `NewService`.

In the Tokio example, you call [`Handle::spawn`](https://docs.rs/tokio-core/0.1.12/tokio_core/reactor/struct.Handle.html#method.spawn), which  requires a `'static` lifetime. The future has reference to `Environment` which does not meet that requirement.

Note that this case uses `Service`.

Comment: The tokio example is basically https://docs.rs/hyper/0.11.15/src/hyper/server/mod.rs.html#362 (part of `hyper::server::Server::run()`) which is using the closure given to `bind()`.   So, the future created by hyper's `Server::run()` will have a non-`'static` reference to `env` too.  But why does this work in hyper, but not here?